# Bootstrap Grid Left Margin Not Aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if this is a bootstrap bug or I am just not understanding the grid system.  I would like the two headers (This Guy, That Guy) to align:

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h3>This Guy</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h3>That Guy</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been playing around with the grid system and in the bottom panel and column widths 1-7 all align the left margins but 9+ column width has a different left alignment.

So my question: Is there a way to align the contents of 6 and 12 column width rows in different panels using Bootstrap 3?

[image: This is what Happens and it Looks Ratchet.]

Comment: If you run the code snippet you will not see the alignment issue unless you select Full page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to have to make your own offset class to make this work.

Every time you start a new row your starting a new column context of 12 columns. Your **This Guy** text is a 10 wide column offset by 1 inside of a 6 wide column. Your **That Guy** text is also a 10 wide column offset by 1 but it is inside of a 12 wide column. Bootstrap uses percentages so the size of `.col-md-offset-1` will be different since the containers that `.col-md-10 .col-md-offset-1` are in are different sizes.

Solution: create your own offset class, something like `.col-md-offset-0-5`.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

@media ( min-width: 992px ) {
  .col-md-offset-0-5 {
    margin-left: 4.1666666%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h3>This Guy</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-0-5">
                <h3>That Guy</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome and will probably use this and mark your answer as correct.  I'm just going to wait to see if any BS genius comes up with a way to achieve this that doesn't require any CSS.  Also, I'm wondering if I should report this as a bug to the Bootstrap team cause I would assume left side margins should align regardless of column width.  Anyway, thanks, your solution is great and working in my responsive layout.

Comment: @JonDiamond I was almost done with my answer and saw this posted which is pretty much what I was going to say. Your 2nd panel has the text as being 'pushed over' because you are off setting a row nested inside a row that has space for it to be offsetted. Create your own offset class or simplify your grid layout so they can match up